# Working with tables having sub-table structure

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, data

Consider two tables

```
Tab1 = Table[{{RandomReal[{0, 1}], 
     RandomReal[{0, 1}]}, {RandomReal[{0, 1}], 
     RandomReal[{0, 1}]}, {RandomReal[{0, 1}], 
     RandomReal[{0, 1}]}}, {i, 1, 5, 1}];
Tab2 = Table[{{RandomReal[{0, 1}], 
     RandomReal[{0, 1}]}, {RandomReal[{0, 1}], 
     RandomReal[{0, 1}]}}, {i, 1, 5, 1}];
```

Their rows are also tables:

```
Tab2//TableForm
```

[image]

I would like to make several manipulations with the tables:

1. Combine the tables in a way such that their sub-tables will be merged. The ugly realization (in the sense that it may be slow if Tab1 has a large size) is

   TabJoined=Table[Join[Tab1[[i]],Tab2[[i]]],{i,1,Length[Tab1],1}];
2. Extract only the first row from each sub-table of Tab1. The ugly realization is

   TabRowExtracted=Table[Tab1[[i]][[2]],{i,1,Length[Tab1],1}];
3. Multiply each 2nh element of the second row of Tab1 by 2:

   TabSecondElementMultiplied=Table[{Tab1[[i]][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpS0h.png)],{Tab1[[i]][[2]][[2]],2*Tab1[[i]][[2]][[2]]},Tab1[[i]][[3]]},{i,1,Length[Tab1],1}];

Could you please tell me whether there are faster realizations of these tasks?

Comment: One can also use `Tab1=RandomReal[{0,1},{5,3,2}]; Tab2=RandomReal[{0,1},{5,2,2}];`.

Comment: @user293787 : thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Join[Tab1,Tab2,2]
Tab1[[;;,2]]
MapAt[2*#&,Tab1,{All,2,2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

That's what I understand from the description in the post. Please provide feedback, if I have not understood it correctly.

```
SeedRandom[1];
Tab1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 3, 2}];
Tab2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 2, 2}];
```

### [image]

`Combine the tables in a way such that their sub-tables will be merged`

```
(TabJoined = 
   Transpose@Catenate[{Transpose@Tab1, Transpose@Tab2}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

---

`Extract only the first row from each sub-table of Tab1`

```
MatrixForm /@ {Tab1, Tab1[[All, All, 1]]}
```

[image]

---

`Multiply each 2nd element of the second row of Tab1 by 2`

[image]